# Unable to lower embedded div element margin

Tags: html, css, margin

In a dialog window, I have the following div "windowSearchDiv" containing the 3 elements shown in the code below. I am trying to vertically align the label, text input, and magnifying glass image. The label and text input are good to go. However, I am for some reason unable to individually move the magnifying glass image in order to align it horizontally with the other 2 elements. What CSS can help me here?

```
<div id="windowSearchDiv">
    <label for="windowMasterSearchBox" id ="windowMasterSearchBoxLabel">Search: </label>
    <input type="text" id="windowMasterSearchBox" placeholder="Enter Student Name..." />
    <a title="Search Students" id="windowMasterMagnifyingGlass"><img src="/images/icons/magnify.gif" alt="Search Students" border="0" /></a>  
</div>
```

`````
#windowMasterMagnifyingGlass {
    float: none;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-right: 351px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: auto;
}


#windowMasterSearchBox, #windowMasterSearchBox {
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

#windowSearchDiv {
    padding: 13px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
````[![The magnifying glass should be lower][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqtzM.png
`````

Comment: Can you provide a rough sketch of how you want this to appear? Without knowing how you want it to appear, it will be very hard to give the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I understood your question right.
Here if a js fiddle,
https://jsfiddle.net/mdsebans/cs7jy0vh/2/

```
                  #windowSearchDiv {
                    padding: 13px;
                    display: flex;
                    max-width: 300px;
                    text-align: center;
                }
```

PS:  is an inline element, so if you make it a block element using display: block, it will start on a new line. 
But I have used flex to fix it.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here. I meant for a horizontal alignment (across the page, not down the page).

Comment: @CDAtheProgrammer I have just updated the answer. Is that what you want? or just label in a line and input an button on another line?